# LASSO regularization when p>n

Tags: machine-learning, lasso

When p>n, number of features greater than the number of observations, LASSO selects only n variables before saturates.

What is the reason for this? 
Although I have read that the reason is the nature of the convex optimization problem, I still can not understand why?

Bear in mind that I am new to this subject.

Comment: Have you considered one of the simpler situations such as $n=1,p=2$? That ought to make the reasons perfectly clear.

Comment: @whuber, sorry, I even do not understand that, may be because I do not understand “the nature of the convex optimization problem”. So,could you please clarify you comments in details?

Comment: Invent data.  Write the model.  Solve it.  You don't need to know a thing about convex optimization, Lasso, or even statistics--that's why this is such an instructive approach.

Comment: @whuber, I am new to this field :(

Comment: Whuber is trying to get you to develop your understanding. Write out a concrete example on paper ( if you get stuck, add example to your question). Try to solve the equations manually. ( Throw convex optimization out of your head)!!!

Comment: @seanv507, but I do not know what to write to develop my understanding. The step by step explanation will allow me to understand the idea.

Comment: @whuber always like the way you encourage people to think more.

Comment: @PeterSmith here is an example n=1, p=2  x = [1,2] y = 5.  can you come up 5  solutions to get y = w_1 * x_1 + w_2 * x_2 (ie w_1,w_2), including solution using only x1 or only x2?    ? what is the l1 norm of the solutions?

Comment: @seanv507 Thanks for your answer, but I do not completely understand, I understand the equation of the straight line and, 2 parameters, one dependent variable, and two independent variables.

Comment: so 1) what are some solutions for w_1 and w_2? [forget the optimum L1 norm for now] 2) what is the L1 norm of the corresponding solutions = |w_1| + |w_2| ?

Comment: @seanv507  1) w_1= (y-w_2*x_2)/x_1, and w_2=(y-w_1*x_1)/x_2.  2) I do not know.

Comment: So now fill in the values for  x1,X2 Y as in my example. What are possible values for w1 and w2

Comment: @seanv507, w_1=5-2*w_2 and w_2=(5-w_1)/2

Comment: so pick an number for w_2 and solve for w_1. then calculate the norms for the solution. in particular try w_2 =0, try w_1 =0 (and solve for w_2) and try  a few things in between. how many solutions are possible?

Comment: @seanv507, if choose w_2=1 that mean w_1=5, if w_1= then w_2=2. When w_1=0 then w_2=2.5. Also if w_2=0 then w_1=5. So the how many solutions depend on how many values for w. If The norm is an absolute value, it will retain the positive number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85971/discussion-between-seanv507-and-peter-smith).

Comment: @seanv507, I have a problem I can not enter the discussion. The smaller the values of w the smaller the l1 norm