Behavior of Lasso Estimator with More Predictors Than Observations (p > n) and Identical Correlations?
What is the behavior of a Lasso estimator if it is used in a dataset with more predictors (p) than observations (n), where all predictors are uncorrelated but highly relevant to

y with exactly the same correlation with

y? Which predictors does the Lasso estimator shrink to zero and which does it retain?
A consistent estimator would not reduce any of the

p variables to zero. However, as I understand, the Lasso estimator would select at most

n predictors. My question is: given these conditions, which predictors does Lasso select and why?

The answer will likely depend on floating point rounding error and be algorithm dependent, because the mathematical answer is "it's perfectly arbitrary."  See our posts about the Lasso for an explanation.

I'm glad to see this compilation of lasso issues.  When $p > n$ no one should accept the results without a simulation showing stability and reliability of the approach.  The results of such simulations are typically quite disconcerting.

Why would the lasso select at most $n$ predictors?

@RichardHardy check out my answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/631944/341520  1) because it answers your and also kind of this question and 2) because I'm very proud of it :)

@whuber thanks. Do you have a link to the post that described that the variable selection would be arbitrary in this case?

One does not need a post for that: the conclusion follows directly from the standard formulation of the Lasso objective function along with the basic theorem of linear algebra that in a vector space of dimension $n,$ any $p\gt n$ vectors are linearly dependent.  I therefore provided a link to a collection of relevant posts so you can select explanations you find most helpful.

The Lasso path is not easily predictable. That makes it difficult to say with a simple formula which parameters are gonna end up in the final minimal L1 norm solution (for two highly correlating features that are very much the same it can be that one of them ends up in the solution and the other not). It is related to saying how many zeros you are gonna get as function of the regularisation parameter https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/639928/how-many-zeroes-from-lasso-linear-regression
